# Is it possible to distinguish similarly named properties belonging to same vertex in a MATCH query in Nebula Graph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I'm playing with Nebula Graph 2.0.0.

I create two tags, both contain a property called `name`:

```
create tag t1(name string)
create tag t2(name string)
```

Now I insert a vertex giving it `t1.name` property:

```
> insert vertex t1(name) values '1': ('first-name');
Execution succeeded (time spent 2730/95913 us)
```

I can see that it can be found by ID:

```
> match (x:t1) where id(x) == '1' return x
+-------------------------------+
| x                             |
+-------------------------------+
| ("1" :t1{name: "first-name"}) |
+-------------------------------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 2713/95756 us)
```

I can also find it by ID *and* `t1.name`:

```
> match (x:t1) where id(x) == '1' and x.name == 'first-name' return x
+-------------------------------+
| x                             |
+-------------------------------+
| ("1" :t1{name: "first-name"}) |
+-------------------------------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 2827/100963 us)
```

Now I assign `t2.name` to the same vertex:

```
insert vertex t2(name) values '1': ('second-name');
```

It is added ok:

```
> match (x:t1) where id(x) == '1' return x

+--------------------------------------------------------+
| x                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ("1" :t1{name: "first-name"} :t2{name: "second-name"}) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 3579/96685 us)
```

And I can still search by ID *and* `t1.name`:

```
> match (x:t1) where id(x) == '1' and x.name == 'first-name' return x
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| x                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ("1" :t1{name: "first-name"} :t2{name: "second-name"}) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 2534/96306 us)
```

But when I search by ID **and** `t2.name`, nothing gets found:

```
> match (x:t1) where id(x) == '1' and x.name == 'second-name' return x
Empty set (time spent 3383/96788 us)
```

So, probably, under the hood, the system thinks I want to search by `t1.name`, so it finds nothing.

In a different session, with tags named differently, I got a different behavior: after adding a second `name` property, I lost ability to search by first `name`, but it was possible to search using the second `name`.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it even legal to have on same vertex properties with same name (but coming from different tags)?
2. If so, how can I ask the query executor to use the specific property (for instance, `t1.name` or `t2.name` and not the one that the system chooses automatically)?

Answer (score 1):

Good catch! Tag is not that native to OpenCypher actually, we nebula is working work support more and more OpenCypher features, and to make it better.
1 Under the hood, the vertex property matching is based on the nebula index, which is now based on one tag only for now(it's actually left RocksDB key match).
2 when the condition/index matching was done, in `MATCH` call, you can return all tags' props belongs to it.

> Is it even legal to have on same vertex properties with same name (but coming from different tags)?

It's legal. But maybe in most cases, the `name` could be the same in both tags?

Actually, here the `WHERE CLAUSE`: `where id(x) == '1'` is like a Primary Key, thus one Vertex is specified already. In your use case, is it still needed for further `AND` condition, please?

> If so, how can I ask the query executor to use the specific property (for instance, t1.name or t2.name and not the one that the system chooses automatically)?

For the reason: 1(prop index can support only one tag/edge type) now, we can only filter within one tag, thus it's either t1.name or t2.name, like t1.name == "foo" and t1.age > 18.

The interesting case you found() is because the prop-index-selection(which is rule based selection, for now, there will be more improvements on this) cannot be done due to `id(v) == 123` is not prop-index based and both tags' prop-indexes are of "name".

To avoid this, maybe we shouldn't allow the same prop-name across tags that belong to the same vertex with different values, this could be improved from docs or code.

Comment: Raised an issue [here](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-graph/issues/1255)